# Complex mysql ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Doing the following query:

```
SELECT title FROM table ORDER BY title
```

gives me:

```
"Hello"
"Zebra"
Apple
Beta
Cactus
```

How would I ORDER BY the first alphabetical character, in order to get:

```
Apple
Beta
Cactus
"Hello"
"Zebra"
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to remove quotes before sorting data. You can easily remove them using `TRIM` function in MySQL as:

```
SELECT title 
FROM table 
ORDER BY TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM title);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
...ORDER BY REPLACE(title, '"', '');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT title FROM table ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING '"' FROM title)
```